# Create a Link to delete a Model Attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

is this possible with Rails 3, meaning some magical simple way?

In my User's table I have a paperclip profile_pic, where the user's image is stored.

i want to make a link that says "Remove your photo" Allow user's to remove any photo for their user profile. Not replace, I have that working, remove, like when they first joined.

Is there a Rails way to make a link like:

```
<a href="">Remove your picture</a>
```

That destroy's just an attribute profile_pic, and then refreshes the page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a magical way to do this. But REST is magical enough.

If you're using resources you'll want to add a new action and a member on that resource something like:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get :kill_off_photo # you can do post, put, delete, etc...
  end
end
```

Then

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def kill_off_photo
    # kill it off
    redirect_to :action => :show # or whatever you need to do here...
  end
end
```

rake routes to see your new route - it should be something like kill_off_photo_user...

Comment: Right but what does the link represent? look like?

Comment: link_to 'Delete this photo', kill_off_photo_user_url(@user) (or whatever you've named the route)